# How to understand which words or phrase brackets point to?

Tags: punctuation, phrase-meaning

#### Example showing how brackets can be confusing

This is a sample from [an O' Level science book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Edexcel-IGCSE-Chemistry-Student-International/dp/0435966898):

> The impure solid is dissolved in the minimum amount of hot water (or any other suitable solvent) [...]

There are two ways to interpret this:

1. *Hot water* (as a whole) is one "suitable solvent", but any other such solvents can used. **The solid is to be dissolved in *a suitable solvent*.**
2. *Water* is a "suitable solvent"; other solvents can also be used. Whatever the solvent is, it has to be *hot*. **The solid is to be dissolved in a *hot solvent*.**

Since this is a science book, the writers have to state the reasons behind everything and ensure clarity. The following sentences (indirectly) clear up the confusion:

> [...], and then allowed to cool again. Most solids are less soluble in
> the cold than in the hot, and so crystals are formed again.

So #2 was the right interpretation.

#### The question

However, in most unscientific day-to-day writing, not every sentence has to be backed up by explanation. So the question is
**how to understand which word(s) or phrase brackets point to?**

Comment: The parentheses applies to hot water, the whole noun phrase, not water alone.  It says use hot water or other liquids that suit as solvents.  If using hot water or anything hot, let it cool.  The fact that the follow-up wants cooling does not require that all solvent be hot.  You may be right about #2, though it's not what I see.

Comment: Your number 2 is incorrect.  “hot water” is a suitable solvent. There are others that may be used- they do not need to be hot.  If it was meant to be hot then it’s written imprecisely.  It should say “... Dissolved in hot solvent (water or other suitable solvent...

Comment: @Jim I think you haven't really understood the context &mdash; `Most solids are less soluble in the cold than in the hot [...]`

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine at least in this specific example, the next 2 sentences establish the context and clear the confusion, but in that very context, Jim is very right to say that whoever wrote the sentence has 'written (it) imprecisely' -- *hot water or any other suitable solvent* (with or without brackets) means 'hot water is a suitable solvent; we can use any other suitable solvent', which is not what the textbook writer intended to say in context! Watch this page for my answer about the proper way(s) to use and interpret brackets without creating confusion.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine - You’ve artificially broken up the sentence. As written in the book, like you say, it’s made clear.  As broken up by you it is ambiguous and the most likely interpretation is not the one meant in the book.  There is no magic way to make your first sentence get interpreted as intended without rewriting it.  In unscientific day-to-day writing (in any writing for that matter)  it’s up to the author to realize when ambiguity exists and either clarify or rewrite to resolve it.

Comment: @Jim I was just going to remind OP that people can make mistakes in their use of brackets and also in their choice of words: while I would always advise the writer to *write as unambiguous a sentence as possible*, I would also advise the reader not to look at the isolated sentence, whatever the choice of words/ punctuation, but *always be sure to interpret it within the overall context* of the sentences that come before and after, which by the way is what OP has rightly done!

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to *parantheses* (meaning: curved brackets) and the term 'brackets' technically refers to *square brackets.* Their purposes are different and distinct, as [this article](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp) explains in detail; I only quote this sentence most relevant to this question:

> Rule 1. Use parentheses to enclose information that clarifies or is used as an aside.
>
> Example: He finally answered (after taking five minutes to think) that he did not understand the question.
>
> (...)The use of parentheses indicates that the writer considered the information less important—almost an afterthought.

Source: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/parens.asp

Based on this explanation, I am inclined to conclude that 'or any other suitable solvent' as used within parentheses in your example should be read as a separate, additional information distinct from 'dissolve in hot water' -- therefore grammatically speaking, *the adjective 'hot' which is applied to 'water' need not be extended to what follows within parentheses.*

However, the rest of the sentence (as it cools down, etc) supplies an important contextual clue that the writer of the sentence actually meant 'any other suitable hot solvent', as you rightly interpreted in context. Correct sentence:

> The impure solid is dissolved in the minimum amount of hot water (or any other suitable ***hot*** solvent) and allowed to cool again.

This is therefore an example where **the original writer made a confusing statement within parentheses** by forgetting to write *hot* in what should have been 'hot solvent'. We should always remember that people can make mistakes in their use of punctuation and also in their choice of words.

While we should ourself be careful to write as unambiguous a sentence as possible, I would also advise any reader not to look at the isolated sentence, whatever the choice of words/ punctuation, but **always be sure to interpret it within the overall context** of the sentences that come before and after, in order to avoid making an error of comprehension.

A common-sense interpretation of the meaning in context is always preferable to a far-fetched technicality-based argument of what the writer *could possibly* have intended, but

***when in doubt, ask for clarification!***

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine in short, the mistake of not writing *'hot solvent'* but only 'solvent' while enclosing information within brackets was made by the original writer of the sentence; however, you made a correct interpretation of the meaning, by reading the sentence in context.

Comment: In the UK parentheses are commonly just called "brackets". [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bracket) defines bracket as "a general name for parenthesis, square bracket, brace" and states "In British English, curved marks like these are also called brackets, but in American English, they are called parenthesis.". Also, your discussion on brackets didn't answer the question, and should only have been a comment.

Comment: @Andy T thanks for the information. By saying 'Also, your discussion on brackets didn't answer the question, and should only have been a comment' do you mean I need not have made the introductory distinction between parentheses and brackets in this answer? My intention was to specify that I would be using the term 'parentheses' to refer to 'round brackets' for the remainder of the answer, and was neant to avoid confusing any reader not fully familiar with brackets and parantheses.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't get that sorry. In that case it is probably appropriate.

Comment: @Andy T your feedback is most welcome because my current English goal is *to write as clearly as possible, absolutely without ambiguity!*

Comment: Thanks to your latest comment on my answer I now understand your logic in interpreting this sentence, and so I've deleted my answer. I obviously wasn't reading properly when I read your answer earlier!

Comment: @AndyT in fact science has its own logic and often the language in a science textbook is 'logical not grammatical.' It is annoying for us to see any linguistic lapse, but science students will understand just fine!